# SSH Access with passwordless Private Key file

Tags: raspbian, ssh, putty

I'm using an rsa 4096-bit keypair to gain passwordless access to a raspberry pi from another pi. If I use the private key on Windows with PuTTY, I am able to access the target pi fine. However, if I try to gain access to the target pi with ssh from another raspberry pi, I am prompted for a password for the key file. There is no password for the key, but if I just press enter, the following is returned (This is while using ssh -vv etc..): `debug2: no passphrase given, try next key`. How am I supposed to enter a blank password if it automatically skips to the next key when no password is entered?

Thanks in advance,
Nathaniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting this I just found a [forum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24821/password-dialog-appears-for-password-less-ssh-private-key) with a related problem. Since I generated the keypair on linux, you must do:
`ssh-keygen -b [NUMBER OF BITS] -C [COMMENT] -f [FILENAME] -P ""`.
The important bit is the `-P ""`, as it seems to ensure ssh does not require the user to enter a password when the key file is used.